# How can I display different types of output in a matix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, matlab-compiler

please consider that I have different types of output in each iteration , how I can show all of them in a matrix?or in a table ? I need to have label for each column and to be accessible when I need it for calling or comparing or etc ...

for example outputs of iterations:
myfilename =

file35.txt

a_Count =

```
 3
```

PPS_Count =

```
16
```

PPP_Count =

```
 8
```

emo =

```
'trust'
```

x = 
     1
for example outputs of iteration 2:
myfilename =

file36.txt

a_Count =

```
 5
```

PPS_Count =

```
10
```

PPP_Count =

```
 8
```

emo =

```
'anger'
```

x = 
     0
for example outputs of iteration 3:
myfilename =

file37.txt

a_Count =

```
 6
```

PPS_Count =

```
32
```

PPP_Count =

```
 8
```

emo =

```
'trust'
```

x = 
     0
thanks in advance.

Comment: Would a [cell](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) array work?

Comment: @kkuilla I was going to say [struct](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) since the fields are already named, but either should work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ... is it possible give ma an example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-structure-array.html) on creating a struct array and documentation for [struct](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html).

In your case what I would do is first create the empty struct and then loop through the files:

```
data_struct = struct('a_Count',{},'PPS_Count',{},'PPP_Count',{},'emo',{},'x',{});

numfiles = 1; % just for testing purposes

for findex = 1:numfiles
    % Code to read in file data goes here. Replace from here to next comment.
    new_a_Count = 3;
    new_PPS_Count = 16;
    new_PPP_Count = 8;
    new_emo = 'trust';
    new_x = 1;
    % Replace down to here populating variables:
    %     new_a_Count, new_PPS_Count, new_PPP_Count, new_emo, new_x
    data_struct(findex).a_Count = new_a_Count;
    data_struct(findex).PPS_Count = new_PPS_Count;
    data_struct(findex).PPP_Count = new_PPP_Count;
    data_struct(findex).emo = new_emo;
    data_struct(findex).x = new_x;
end;

% display all values in data_struct(1):
disp("data_struct(1) = "); 
disp(data_struct(1));

disp("\n");
% display just the first field "a_Count"
disp("data_struct(1).a_Count = "); 
disp(data_struct(1).a_Count);
```

Note that you can call those new variables anything, including the same names as the struct fields. Here's the output you should get when you run this:

```
data_struct (1) =
{
  PPP_Count = 8
  PPS_Count = 16
  a_Count = 3
  emo = trust
  x = 1
}

data_struct(1).a_Count =
3
```

Comment: Thank you very much .. but I have an error in the line : data_struct(k).a_Count = new_a_Count;                               ??? Undefined function or variable 'new_a_Count'.

Comment: `new_a_Count` is what I used as the variable read from your file. I'll modify my code so it's executable and you can see what's going on.

Comment: Thank you very much ... it was a big help to me . :)